# Can't pass a class as a parameter to a command

Tags: wpf

I'm new to programming and I have difficulty with passing my class that I created in `<Window.Resources>` in `XAML` as a parameter in the command.

```
  <Window.Resources>
      <local:RegisterWindowViewModel x:Key="RegViewModel"/>
      <local:RegisterValidationConverter x:Key="RegValid"/>
      <local:UsersViewModel x:Key="UVM"/>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Here is the button with the command binding

```
    <Button Name="signupButton" DataContext="{StaticResource UVM}"
            Height="50" Width="150" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" 
            FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold"
            Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
            Command="{Binding GetRegisterItemCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding RegViewModel}">
        Sign Up
    </Button>
```

I think that this code `CommandParameter="{Binding RegViewModel}"` is incorrect, but I just dont know how to replace it...

Because of this I get a `null` instead of my object in the command function.
The function itself is ok; I've tested it a lot and I've tried to pass another object(`TextBox`) for example and it worked fine.

I just do not understand the syntax.

Is it even possible to pass a class that is created in the resources?

I will be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are trying it would suggest that it can find the `RegViewModel` on the current `DataContext`.

To point to your viewmodel itself, you can say that the source of your binding is your `RegViewmodel` with the following changes. In this case, the full `RegViewModel` will be passed to the `CommandParameter`

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource RegViewModel}}"
```